# クラスター アイコンをクリックイベントで変更したい

Tags: javascript, google-maps

googlemapsAPIを使用してクラスターを表示しています。
クラスターをクリックした時に、アイコンを変更したいのですが変わりません。
下記を参考にしています。
https://googlemaps.github.io/v3-utility-library/classes/_google_markerclustererplus.markerclusterer.html#setimagepath
`clusterMarker.getImagePath()`で、`/orange.svg`の取得はできており
`clusterMarker.setImagePath("/red.svg");`すると、オブジェクトは`/red.svg`に変更されていますが地図上のアイコンには反映されません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
// 単一マーカー
singleMarkersList = markerList.map((marker, i) => {
    const singleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: marker.position,
    info: marker.info,
    icon: createSingleMarker("orange")
    })

    // 単一マーカークリックイベント付与
    singleMarker.addListener("click", (e) => {
    togglearkerImage(singleMarker);
    showMarkerInfo([singleMarker]);
    });

    return singleMarker
});

// クラスターマーカー
clusterMarker = new MarkerClusterer(map, singleMarkersList, {
    imageExtension: "svg",
    // クラスタークリック時にzoomさせない
    zoomOnClick: false,
    styles: [{
    url: "/orange.svg",
    }]
});

// クラスターアイコンクリック時イベント付与
google.maps.event.addListener(clusterMarker, "clusterclick", (cluster) => {
    clusterMarker.setImagePath("/red.svg");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

自己解決メモ

```
// クラスタのstyle定義
const clusterMarkerOptions = {
    imageExtension: "svg",
    styles:  [{
      url: "icon-red.svg",
    }, {
      url: "icon-orange.svg",
    },
}

    // 単一マーカー
singleMarkersList = markerList.map((marker, i) => {
    const singleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: marker.position,
    })

    return singleMarker
});

    // クラスターマーカー描画
    clusterMarker = new MarkerClusterer(map, singleMarkersList,　clusterMarkerOptions);
    clusterMarker.setCalculator({
            text: "クラスターラベルtext", 
            // icon-red.svgが表示
            index: 1
      });
  

 // クラスターアイコンクリック時イベント付与
    google.maps.event.addListener(clusterMarker, "clusterclick", () => {
      clusterMarker.setCalculator({
            text: "クラスターラベルtext", 
            // icon-red.svgが表示
            index: 2
      });
    clusterMarker.redraw_();
    });
```